# Error populating dropdown menu from database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to auto populate a dropdown menu with data from mysl db. The dropdown should display type `inactive` and `active` for user to pick. Below I have the table structure and the sql query from the php side. The dropdown is not displaying any values at all.

```
CREATE TABLE academy
(
  academy_id int(11) not null auto_increment,
  name varchar(25) not null,
  type enum('INACTIVE','ACTIVE') DEFAULT 'ACTIVE' NOT NULL,
  primary key (id),
 );
```

php

```
Type: <select name="select_type">
<?php
        $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        } 

        $dropDownQuery = "SELECT type FROM academy";

        if ($result = $mysqli->query($dropDownQuery)) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                $type = $row['type'];
                echo "<option value=\"$type\">$type</option>";
            }
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: r u getting any javascript error??

Comment: whats happening, Is there any error

Comment: what's with the variable `$type` when you're using `$partner`

Comment: @AmanVarshney Not using javascript. only php

Comment: @SunilKumar no error displaying, nothing displays in the dropdown

Comment: @DrixsonOseña sorry `$partner` was not intended to be there, i made the change to `$type`

Comment: check if you are getting data or not 'echo $partner;' if yes then `Replace $type with $partner` and check my answer

Comment: @user2970730 add `echo mysqli_num_rows($result);` before `while` and tell whats it giving

Comment: while using echo, you have to concatenate php variable, try this   echo "<option value=".$type.">".$type."</option>";

Comment: @user2970730 check your table it has some row or not?

Comment: @user2970730 you sure you have records on your academy table?!

Comment: @SunilKumar I came across this [link](http://jadendreamer.wordpress.com/2011/03/16/php-tutorial-put-mysql-enum-values-into-drop-down-select-box/). I am trying to accomplish that.

Comment: @DrixsonOseña I am trying to acomplish this [link](http://jadendreamer.wordpress.com/2011/03/16/php-tutorial-put-mysql-enum-values-into-drop-down-select-box/)

Answer (score 1):

`$type` is not defined in your code.

Replace `$partner` with `$type`

```
 $type = $row['type'];

 echo "<option value=\"$type\">$type</option>";
```

Comment: is the issue here `type enum('INACTIVE','ACTIVE') DEFAULT 'ACTIVE' NOT NULL,` ?

Comment: @user2970730 add `echo mysqli_num_rows($result);` before `while` and tell whats it giving

Comment: Nothing is being echo

Comment: @user2970730 `check your table` it has some row or not?

Comment: dont use `echo` use `var_dump` for troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

```
   $dropDownQuery = "SELECT `type` FROM academy";
        if ($result = $mysqli->query($dropDownQuery)) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                $partner = $row['type'];
                printf ('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $partner, $partner);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);


   if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    } 

    $table_name = "academy";
    $column_name = "type";

    echo "<select name=\"$column_name\"><option>Select one</option>";
    $q = "SELECT COLUMN_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = '$table_name' AND COLUMN_NAME = '$column_name'";
    $r = mysqli_query($mysqli, $q);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
    //print_r($row);
    $enumList = explode(",", str_replace("'", "", substr($row['COLUMN_TYPE'], 5, (strlen($row['COLUMN_TYPE'])-6))));
    //print_r($enumList);
    foreach($enumList as $value){
        echo "<option value='$value'>$value</option>";
    }
    echo "</select></br>";
```